# Name Proper Casing

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

Can you help me in having a proper casing,
I have this code...

```
 Private Function NameCsing(ByVal sValue As String) As String
    Dim toConvert As String() = sValue.Split(" ")
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To toConvert.Length - 1
        Dim converted As String = ""
        If toConvert(i).Contains("~") Then
            Dim toName As String() = toConvert(i).Split("~")
            Dim sName As String = ""
            For n As Integer = 0 To toName.Length - 1
                Dim sconvert As String = ""
                If n = 0 Then
                    sName = StrConv(toName(n), VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                Else
                    sName += StrConv(toName(n), VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                End If
            Next
            converted = sName
        Else
            converted = toConvert(i)
        End If
        lst.Add(converted)
    Next
    Dim ret As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            ret = lst(0)
        Else
            ret += " " + lst(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

My codes will just output like this "McDonalds" is you input "mc~donalds"
now my problem is eh I input "evalue", my output must be "eValue"

Comment: Why should "evalue" be converted to "eValue"? According to the rules shouldn't the input string be "e~value"?

Comment: because it is in the rules that should be 'eValue'

Comment: no when I input it 'e~value' it will convert into EValue because all my conversion is in Propercasing

Comment: Yes, you are correct but, still, there is no rule in your code to set "evalue" to "eValue". Why/how should the program decide when to "proper-case" the word "value" inside the "evalue" string?

Comment: yes but not only eValue.. but some of the words.. how

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know how to treat a special string is to code it yourself from a list of rules:

```
Private Function NameCsing(ByVal sValue As String) As String
    If sValue.Trim.ToLower = "evalue" Then Return "eValue"
    'Then process any other special cases
End Function
```